# Split XML into chunks of 5 each using XPATH

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, transformation

Am looking for XPATH expressions which splits the XML into chunks of 5 elements each. Is this achievable via single XPATH expression, since the tool I work with accept only single like expressions and not XSLT. Something like group by the count of 5 or so.

Comment: Sounds like a task for the XSLT-2.0 feature [`xsl:for-each-group`](https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/11/05/tr.html).

Comment: Yes I know that. But this stupid tool takes only XPATH expressions, not XSLT. They hate simple life :)

Comment: Which version of XPath does the tool support? How do you expect pure XPath to structure the result, i.e. to separate groups? That is pretty much a job for XQuery or XSLT unless you have XPath 3.1 and maps/arrays to create some result structure.

Comment: it supports 3.0. I think this is not attainable via xpath, i am doing a workaround at the source itself. thanks all.

Answer (score 3):

With XPath 3.1 you can at least structure the result in some way to have chunks of 5 elements, for instance

```
let $items := root/item,
    $size := 5
return
    for $i in (1 to count($items))[position() mod $size = 1]
    return array{$items[position() = ($i to ($i + $size - 1))]}
```

returns a sequence of arrays where each array has `$size` items (respectively the last array the remaining items).

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiQZDbd shows the result (note that the tool supports XQuery 3.1 where you have much easier and efficient ways with grouping and windowing but I tried to write a pure XPath 3.1 expression).

A different result would be a single array where each item is a sequence of `$size` elements e.g.

```
declare namespace array = "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array";

array:join(
    let $items := root/item,
        $size := 5
    return
    for $i in (1 to count($items))[position() mod $size = 1]
    return [$items[position() = ($i to ($i + $size - 1))]]
)
```

The `declare` is again XQuery, with pure XPath 3.1 you need to use an API specific way or perhaps a tool that makes sure that namespace for the array functions is declared.

Answer (score 0):

If your tool accepts only XPath 1.0 then you can use `position()` as `//item[(position()=1) or (position() <= 5)]` and then shift the conditions to 6,10 etc.

```
xmllint --xpath '//item[(position()=1) or (position() <= 5)]' test.xml | sed -re 's%(</[^>]+>)%\1\n%g'
```

Result

```
<item>1</item>
<item>2</item>
<item>3</item>
<item>4</item>
<item>5</item>
```